# swift3 firebase update and get error for FIRAuth.auth().currentUser?.email

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

Before firebase update, this code is working well for email login and print out the user email.
But after I update firebase today, the below code has an error.
Please kindly help to fix it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    print(FIRAuth.auth().currentUser?.email)
}
```

after change the code FIRAuth to Auth and run the app.
I input the email and password and press the login button, it shows the below error.

[image]

Comment: Auth.auth().currentUser?.email

Comment: @DoesData it doesn’t work, when the app running it comes error

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: please kindly see my update

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Turn off spell checking and correction on the text fields. For some reason the app is unable to download the spellchecking assets from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me:

```
let email = emailText.text!
let password = passwordText.text!

Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

if error == nil {

/* user is signed in */

} else {

/* email or password is taken OR error connecting to Firebase */

}

}
```

To get the current user email try this:

```
print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email as String!)
```